# Props from <Link> not being sent when sent to same path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is currently what I have set up for the links. What happening right now is when I navigate to /profile from any other component, it will work properly. It will navigate to '/profile', with the correct key and this.props.location.state value for menu;

This list is from a navbar component I have at the top of the '/', and '/profile'.

```
                                        <li> 
                                            <Link to={{
                                                pathname: '/profile',
                                                key: 1,
                                                state: {
                                                    menu: 'My Profile'
                                                }
                                            }}>
                                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                                My Profile
                                            </Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li> 
                                            <Link to={{
                                                pathname: '/profile',
                                                key: 2,
                                                state: {
                                                    menu: 'My Products'
                                                }
                                            }}>
                                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                                                My Products
                                            </Link>
                                        </li>
```

`<Route exact path="/profile" render={(routeProps) => <UserProfile key={Date.now()} {...routeProps}/>} />`
This is the line controlling my routing in my App.js file

My problem is if I'm already on '/profile', it won't work properly. It will mount the profile component again, but the key and menu of this.props.location won't be updated.

EG: If I use the list button 1 from '/', it will go to '/profile' with key = 1, and this.props.location.state = 'My Profile'. If I then proceed to click the second button, it will mount the profile component again, but key=1, and this.props.location.state = 'My Profile'.

This only seems to occur when I am already at '/profile', as navigating from anywhere else will result in the correct key and state values. The component isn't having a problem re-rendering since I currently have a log in componentDidMount() every time it mounts. It seems to mount without properly changing the key and state.

Comment: did you check that in componentDidUpdate?

Comment: @NishargShah in my componentDidUpdate(prevProps) I have ```componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

  console.log(prevProps.location);
  console.log(this.props.location);
  console.log(this.props);


  if (this.props.location.state != prevProps.location.state)
  {
   console.log('state changed');
  }

 }``` It never fires though, because when the page re-renders the props arent changing which is my problem. Also, componentDidUpdate() wont fire if the component is remounted every time its routed and remounted.